# Installing Postal Error:'./docker-compose.yml' is invalid, Unsupported config option for services.runner: 'profiles'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postal

I tried to Install the postal Mail server. But there is a problem with the "docker-compose.yml". I get the following Error Message: "ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services.runner: 'profiles'"

The File is the following:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    image: ghcr.io/postalserver/postal:2.1.4
    command: postal web-server
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /opt/postal/config:/config

  smtp:
    image: ghcr.io/postalserver/postal:2.1.4
    command: postal smtp-server
    network_mode: host
    cap_add:
      - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    volumes:
      - /opt/postal/config:/config

  worker:
    image: ghcr.io/postalserver/postal:2.1.4
    command: postal worker
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /opt/postal/config:/config

  cron:
    image: ghcr.io/postalserver/postal:2.1.4
    command: postal cron
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /opt/postal/config:/config

  requeuer:
    image: ghcr.io/postalserver/postal:2.1.4
    command: postal requeuer
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /opt/postal/config:/config

  runner:
    profiles: ["tools"]
    image: ghcr.io/postalserver/postal:2.1.4
    command: postal
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /opt/postal/config:/config
```

Comment: what's your docker-compose version (`docker-compose --version`)?

Comment: It´s the version 1.27.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your docker-compose version.
Service profiles only got introduced in Version [1.28.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1280) and even after that still had some bugs.
Despite that docker-compose v2 is planned to become the standard.